# NSString being released even after being retained

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, memory-management, nsstring

I have an NSString that I've retained, and the only place I release it is in the dealloc method. For some reason, however, later in the program when I try to reference it (its length, specifically), I get a crash, saying [CFString length]:message sent to deallocated instance 0xff32c50.

I explicitly retain the string earlier in the program. Is there any reason why this would be happening? Any help is appreciated.

The string, entityParameter, is declared in the header, and defined later.
Here is some of the code:
`entityParameter = [[EntitySearchWindow stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"f();"] retain];`

The place where I'm getting the crash looks like this:
`if([entityParameter length] != 0 && entityParameter != nil)
{
return;
}`

Comment: Without seeing some code this is impossible to answer.

Comment: If you could, please post your code so we can see what you are doing wrong. Also, if your using XCode4 go to Product->Analyse and look for any early release warnings.

Comment: Have already used the analyze tool, nothing out of the ordinary there.

Comment: Have you already confirmed that entityParameter is not nil after the evaluation?

Comment: You don't need to do both those checks in the conditional; if `entityParameter` is `nil`, then `length` will give you 0 anyways.

Comment: Thanks, that was something that confused me before, so I just put both. Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: I'd say it's good to be explicit about both checks just for style reasons, although the order you have them in is a bit silly.

Comment: More to the point: You've shown us a random couple of lines of code, but the real problem is almost certainly elsewhere. Follow @bbum's advice and use the Zombies template in Instruments; it will tell you exactly where you tried to use the dead object, and where that object was created, every time and place it was retained, and every time and place it was released.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have an NSString that I've retained,
>   and the only place I release it is in
>   the dealloc method. For some reason,
>   however, later in the program when I
>   try to reference it (its length,
>   specifically), I get a crash, saying
>   [CFString length]:message sent to
>   deallocated instance 0xff32c50.

Obviously, it isn't retained, then.

If by "retained" you mean "assigned to a property", are you doing:

```
self.prop = [NSString ...];
```

Or:

```
prop = [NSString ...];
```

Because the former will retain (if the property is declared as `retain`) whereas the latter will not.  Note that NSString properties should generally be declared `copy`, but that is orthogonal to the question).

If your code is as written:

```
entityParameter = [[EntitySearchWindow stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"f();"] retain];
```

And you really do only `release` it in `dealloc`, then make sure your containing object hasn't already been deallocated.   That may be happening.  Or it might be that you've leaked the string reference somewhere and spuriously deleted it without a  retain.

Using Zombie detection in instruments with "track retain/release events" (or whatever it is called) should show you every last retain/release event on the object, including the one the blew up.

Comment: By retain, I meant I wrote `entityParameter = [EntitySearchWindow stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"f();"]; [entityParameter retain];` Will try using the track retain/release events in instruments.

Comment: Update: Here is a screen shot of the analytics after running the zombie instrument. Not sure what to do with this. http://i53.tinypic.com/14xl6x3.png

Comment: Okay, I solved it, though it's a pretty bad solution. The problem was the method got called five times, and after the first run through, the string was autoreleased for some reason. I just added another retain within the method itself, so each time it'd retain, have another reference to itself, and then autorelease one of the references before deallocating in dealloc.

Comment: That doesn't make sense and indicates another bug.  Please post the body of the method.

Comment: In order to display everything, i'd have to post the entire body of the class. I'm working on a complex web application, and webViewDidFinishLoad thinks its loading five different pages, when really it's only one (with five sections). That's why it was being released before the second runthrough of webViewDidFinishLoad. I then retain it each time webViewDidFinishLoad is called, so there's an extra reference to it each time, preventing a call to an already deallocated object.

Comment: Bummer.  It still sounds like you are fixing symptoms, not the underlying problem.  Obviously, figuring out why webViewDidFinishLoad is being called 5 times is critical.

Comment: @Mason: There is no “autoreleased for some reason”. Autoreleasing is an act, not an event that randomly occurs. In Instruments, look at the stack traces for those events. Two questions that come to my mind: (1) You say that the string is created by `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`, but Instruments shows `stringWithFormat:`. Why is that? (2) What does GraphicsServices have to do with this string? The stack traces will tell you (or at least lead you toward) the answers to both questions.